# How to store an image as a link inside my Database in laravel-8 that will be used in frontend Vue.js?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I developed one controller, model, and migration table. I want to store an image as a URL in my database  which should be displayed on my frontend page, for that I write in the migration table as a file column as a binary it's not storing as a URL format inside my database, please help me how to store that image path as a url-link inside my database  which should be reused in my frontend pages

**Books migration table**

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->binary('file')->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity');
            // $table->string('file')->nullable();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

**FileController.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\StaticAnalysis\Cache;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BookResource;

class FileController extends Controller {    
    public function upload(Request $request) {
        $book = new Books();
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->file=$request->file('file')->store('apiDocs','public');
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();
        $book->save();
        return new BookResource($book);
    }
}
```

**Books.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'file',
        'price',
        'name',
        'quantity',
        'description',
        'author'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Return a key-value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
   
    //inverse one to many
   public function user() {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

**How inside my database storing**

```sql
mysql> select * from books \G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 1
       name: Vue
     author: flysystem
      price: 999
       file: 0x617069446F63732F4953356145597479614A657361616D395838495933426D545171696E47733274346C6C54774857732E706E67
   quantity: 2
description: laravel
    user_id: 3
 created_at: 2021-07-06 11:40:16
 updated_at: 2021-07-06 11:40:16

1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this ways step by step:

0- Change your column type of migration from binary to text or string.

1- Create function that store your files in storage: (You can create this function in trait for reusability)

```
protected function uploadImages($file, $path)
{
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $filePath = $path . "/$date->year";
    $filename = $date->timestamp . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    return $file->storeAs(
        $filePath, $filename, 'public'
    );
}
```

this function return path to your file like: `images/books/2021/YOUR_FILE_NAME`

2- use this function for uploading files:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('image'), '/images/books');
}
```

3- Create symlink to your storage:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

4- Finally, in vue you can access images like:

```
<img :src="getImage(book.image)" class="img-fluid index-post-image rounded" :alt="post.slug">

methods : {
  getImage(image) {
    return process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_URL + '/storage/' + image;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer inorder to write  a new function can i write in my upload function only

Comment: i want to write image upload things inside my upload function only, how to write this store and uploadImage function in my upload function

Comment: Actually yes, i write this code for you for reusabillity purpose.

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
{
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $filePath = '/images/books/' . $date->year";
    $filename = $date->timestamp . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $imagesUrl = $file->storeAs(
        $filePath, $filename, 'public'
    );
}

Comment: @Abolfazi Mohajeri , when i am trying to copy the code in my upload function it's not happening please help me

Comment: is it possible to call store function inside my upload function for uploading image

Comment: @Sravani did you follow this ways? it should work 100%

Comment: @Sravani if you have more question get in touch with me by abmohajeri1@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

change the file type to string and in your controller use the method below to save your file in backend public folder and the link in the database.

**Books migration table**

```
$table->string('file')->nullable();
```

**FileController.php**

```
$image = $request->file;
$rand = hexdec(uniqid()); //random unique name for the file
$extension = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
$img_name = $rand.'.'.$extension;
$up_location = 'image/'; //location in public folder to save file
$image->move($up_location, $img_name);
$book->file= = $up_location.$img_name;
```

it will save the image as: `image/*filename*`, you can add your backend `url` in front of it to read it in frontend.

for example if your backend url is `api.domain.com`:

```
<img :src="'api.domain.com'+book.file">
```